# can I travel from US to Greece via Switzerland on either a US passport or an expiring EU member state passport?

Tags: schengen, passports

I intended to travel from US to Greece via Switzerland (airport only), but I just noticed that my EU member state passport is expiring shortly after my return flight date (i.e., it does not clear the 3 months rule).

I also have a US passport with no validity issues and the trip would be shorter than 90 days.

I tried to Google this but most resources are unclear on which rules apply to non-EU citizens vs EU citizens and travel within Schengen vs entering Schengen.

Would it be OK for me to use my EU passport or should I use my US passport instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "3 month" rule only applies to citizens from non-EU countries.  You will have no issues entering/travelling within the EU/Schengen Region using your EU passport with less than 3 months validity.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica You can NOT use an EU passport to enter the US. Doing so would require an ESTA (or visa), and an ESTA can not legally be obtained by a US citizen.

Comment: Thanks, you're quite right. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 3):

The three-month rule does not apply to you as an EU citizen but if you are having any issue at the departure airport, you should feel free to use whatever is convenient and show your US passport.

Comment: The difficult that _could_ arise with the US passport is that passport control and airline **may** ask for a return ticket. But the EU passport, as long as it is valid, is enough.

Comment: @jcaron The EU passport is an obvious first choice but I wanted to highlight the fact that there is absolutely no reason to be worried about using the US passport either (as people often imagine you may be required to use the EU passport to enter the Schengen area or have to use the same passport when boarding the plane and crossing the border, neither of which are true). A return ticket is not required and unlikely to be needed to board the plane.